# Clustering doesn't work properly in iOS 13

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am doing clustering of Annotations.

The below code works fine and clusters the points correctly in iOS 11 & iOS 12.

This fails to cluster the points decluster the points in iOS 13.

I am not using any beta versions.

The TTMapView class is wrapper for MKMapView.

```swift
class TTMapView: UIView {

    var mapView = MKMapView()
    private var mapObjects: Dictionary<TTShape, MKShape?> = [:]
    private var _isClusteringEnabled = true

    func addMarker(_ marker: TTPoint) -> TTPoint {
        removeMarker(marker)
        let coordinate = marker.coordinate
        let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = convertTTCoordinateToCLLocationCoordinate2D(coordinate)
        pointAnnotation.title = marker.title
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = marker.subtitle
        mapObjects.updateValue(pointAnnotation, forKey: marker)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
        return marker
    }
}

extension TTMapView: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        if _isClusteringEnabled {
            let point = mapObjects.filter ({ $0.value === annotation }).first?.key as? TTPoint
            print("point ", point)
            return TTClusterAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: TTClusterAnnotationView.ReuseID, image: point?.image, color: point?.tintColor)
        } else {
            let reuseId = "simplePin"
            var pinAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
            if pinAnnotationView == nil {
                pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                pinAnnotationView?.isDraggable = true
                pinAnnotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            }
            return pinAnnotationView
        }
    }
}

class TTClusterAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    /// Use this Id for setting annotation
    static let ReuseID = "clusterAnnotation"

    init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?, image: UIImage?, color: UIColor? = nil) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Enable clustering by just setting the clusteringIdentifier
        clusteringIdentifier = "clusteringIdentifier"
        glyphImage = image
        glyphTintColor = color
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()
        displayPriority = .required
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the cluster annotation view (this is the annotation view for the cluster, not to be confused with your existing annotation view that has a `clusteringIdentifier`, which I’ve renamed to `CustomAnnotationView` to avoid confusion) have a `displayPriority` of `.required`:

```
class CustomClusterAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        displayPriority = .required
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            displayPriority = .required
        }
    }
}
```

Then register that class:

```
mapView.register(CustomClusterAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

And then use it:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    if annotation is MKClusterAnnotation {
        return nil
    }

    ...
}
```

---

A few unrelated observations:

1. I’d suggest just adding your image and color properties to a custom annotation type rather than having `viewFor` filter through `mapObjects`. So:

   ```
   class CustomAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
       let image: UIImage
       let color: UIColor

       init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, image: UIImage, color: UIColor) {
           self.image = image
           self.color = color
           super.init()
           self.coordinate = coordinate
           self.title = title
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, if you use that rather than `MKPointAnnotation`, your custom annotation view can pull the color and image info right out of the annotation.

   ```
   class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
       static let reuseID = "CustomAnnotationView"

       override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
           super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
           updateForAnnotation()
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }

       override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
           didSet {
               updateForAnnotation()
           }
       }
   }

   private extension CustomAnnotationView {
       func updateForAnnotation() {
           clusteringIdentifier = "CustomAnnotationView"
           displayPriority = .required
           if let annotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation {
               glyphImage = annotation.image
               glyphTintColor = annotation.color
           } else {
               glyphImage = nil
               glyphTintColor = nil
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, above I’m resetting the cluster identifier, image, glyph, etc. in the `didSet` of `annotation`. This enables the reuse of annotation views. (See next point.)
2. The reuse logic for your pin annotation view is not correct. And you’re not doing reuse at all if clustering is turned on. If targeting iOS 11 and later, I’d use `dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier:for:)` which takes care of all of this for you. So, I can register this reuse id:

   ```
   mapView.register(CustomAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: CustomAnnotationView.reuseID)
   ```

   And I’d repeat that process for the “simple pin” annotation view that you show if you turn off clustering.

   ```
   mapView.register(CustomSimplePinAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: CustomSimplePinAnnotationView.reuseID)
   ```

   And

   ```
   class CustomSimplePinAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
       static let reuseID = "CustomSimplePinAnnotationView"

       override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
           super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
           isDraggable = true
           canShowCallout = true
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
   }
   ```

   And then your `viewFor` is simplified:

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       switch annotation {
       case is MKUserLocation:
           return nil

       case is MKClusterAnnotation:
           return nil

       default:
           if _isClusteringEnabled {
               return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: CustomAnnotationView.reuseID, for: annotation)
           } else {
               return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: CustomSimplePinAnnotationView.reuseID, for: annotation)
           }
       }
   }
   ```